# How come I can't use a variable to access a string from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I get this to work?

```
var colors;  
colors = ['white', 'black', 'custom'];  
var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);  
el.textContent = colors[r];
```

Comment: The way your question is formatted at the moment doesn't fit with stack overflow rules and will likely attract a large number of down votes or be closed very quickly. To avoid this, it's a good idea to edit your question to provide clear examples of your overall problem, what issues you're facing, what you have tried, and why those don't work. Also, it's worth searching to see if your question has already been asked before.

Comment: `colors[r]` will evaluate to a value contained in the array, as expected. Make sure to 1) find out the *actual problems* (ie. read messages on the error console) and 2) use *valid supporting evidence* in such questions. Try this test: would it run on JSFiddle? If not, does the reason of failure relate to the purported problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as long as "el" is obtained correctly see http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/49gf18xj/

```
<div id="el"></div>
var el = document.getElementById("el");
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the wrong id value haha

Answer (score 0):

many (if not all) programming languages support this. you can dynamically access elements inside arrays (and properties from objects also) without the need to hardcode the  index (or name of property) by using variables.

there must be something else wrong in your code. probably in the way `el` is defined and/or initialized